# Is it possible to use java.util.Properties-files to set size of window when it is opened?

Tags: java, user-interface

How can I use java.util.Properties-files in my application to remember its status from the last time. I want my application is opened at the same place and with the same size as it had when it was last closed.This is part of my code:

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Infinity");

    v demo = new v();
    frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(740, 480));
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Properties prop = new Properties();

            // add some properties
            prop.setProperty("Height", "200");
            prop.put("Width", "1500");

            // print the list 
            try {
                // store the properties list in an output stream
                prop.store(System.out, "PropertiesDemo");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: yes, I upload my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply call the [setProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.  Then, right before you close, call [save](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29).

When you start up, call [load](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) the same way you already are.

---

Even better than all of this, use [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).

Comment: @user3061922 1) you aren't calling `load`.  You just "stored" on the console. You need to put it in a file.  You know what would be an even better solution to this?  The [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class.

Comment: What do you mean with load? I have to make txt file with properties inside the file, and then load it?

Comment: @user3061922 not if you use `Preferences`.  Use `Preferences`.